# How to edit data in mongoDB with pymongo

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo

So I have the following data:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b4cfdae44a8d900048661b0"
    },
    "type": "user",
    "user_name": "alexrotar",
    "order_number" = 23
}
```

How could I edit the id number? By searching for the user_name?

This is the way I'm searching to get the order_name:

```
curs = collection.find({"user_name":alexrotar}, {"user_id":True, "_id":False})
        for item in curs:
            get_user = item.get("order_number", None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the reference code that you can apply, is very self explanatory

## Function to update record to mongo db

def update():
    try:
    criteria = raw_input('\nEnter id to update\n')
    name = raw_input('\nEnter name to update\n')
    age = raw_input('\nEnter age to update\n')
    country = raw_input('\nEnter country to update\n')

```
db.Employees.update_one(
    {"id": criteria},
    {
    "$set": {
        "name":name,
        "age":age,
        "country":country
    }
    }
)
```

Let me clarify that it will only work if the "user_name" is unique. Give it a try and let me know.

More reference for all the basic functions are here:

https://codehandbook.org/pymongo-tutorial-crud-operation-mongodb/

Regards,

DH